# How to regenerate /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg on Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

Suppose one deleted (or damaged) the following file.

```
/etc/apt/trustdb.gpg
```

How to regenerate it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found these 2 methods for doing it. The first seems like the safest way to do it.

#### Method #1 - using apt

```
$ sudo -i
$ apt-get clean
$ cd /var/lib/apt
$ mv lists lists.old
$ mkdir -p lists/partial
$ apt-get clean
$ apt-get update
```

#### Method #2 - apt-key

You can use this command to get `apt-key` to generate the corresponding `gpg` command to download the appropriate key for Canonical.

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
gpg: requesting key 437D05B5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" 25 new signatures
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg: new signatures: 25
```

#### What's happening?

You can spy a bit on the second method if you use this command:

```
$ sudo -i
$ bash -x apt-key update |& less
+ set -e
+ unset GREP_OPTIONS
++ mktemp
+ SECRETKEYRING=/tmp/tmp.ZhVikJSB3s
+ trap 'rm -f '\''/tmp/tmp.ZhVikJSB3s'\''' 0 HUP INT QUIT ILL ABRT FPE SEGV PIPE TERM
+ GPG_CMD='gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.ZhVikJSB3s'
++ id -u
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
++ apt-config shell TRUSTDBDIR Dir::Etc/d
+ eval 'TRUSTDBDIR='\''/etc/apt/'\'''
...
```

This command can also be used, **as a regular user, not root!**:

```
$ apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5                             Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.kZ1TEwcI5s --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
gpg: requesting key 437D05B5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: error writing keyring `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg': file write error
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" 26 new signatures
gpg: error reading `[stream]': file write error
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg:         new signatures: 26
```

#### References

- [Fixing apt-get GPG Invalid Signature in ubuntu](http://tips4admin.com/blog/2013/10/fixing-apt-get-gpg-invalid-signature-in-ubuntu/)
- [Errors when updating package list with apt-get on (K)ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/585743/errors-when-updating-package-list-with-apt-get-on-kubuntu)
- [Apt-get Update GPG Key Errors and Fix](http://systembash.com/content/apt-get-update-gpg-key-errors-and-fix/)

Comment: why `keyserver.ubuntu.com` for Debian?